# Godot: _process() vs _physics_process(): I need a valuable example

Tags: godot

There are lot of links on the web, but no one answers correctly to my question... I copy/paste my "official" code just after my reflexion, because I dont understand when/why/how to **properly** use `_process()` vs `_physics_process()`.

I see that the principle is the same as in Unity: `_process()` is called as soon as it can and not consistently (sometimes more, sometimes less), unlike `_physics_process()`. And what surprised me were the officially "recommended best practices" in Unity, which correspond to my code here on Godot, whereas in the official Godot documentation [(see the link here)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/2d_movement.html), they read the inputs **in** `_physics_process()`!

With a trace(`print("...")`) in both methods, I see that `_process()` is called 5 times at the beginning before `_physics_process()`. This means, in practice, that, for example, if the player has pressed + released the "up" button in the meantime, nothing happens (which is logical). But conversely, if there is a big lag, my code ignores player inputs (because `_process()` is no longer called), but continues/finishes/physical movements, which seems identical to the behavior of all online games (LoL are you there?). So... I don't understand... because if they had wanted, they would have made a single routine, and they wouldn't have differentiated `_process()` vs `_physics_process()` ...

So I've come up with this *"theoretically" good code* which is **much longer** than in any example you can find on the Web. To make it work, create a 3D project, add a `KinematicBody` and in this node, add a `Mesh` and  a `CollisionShape` (a sphere). And add this script to the `KinematicBody`.

```
extends KinematicBody

export var SPEED:int = 6
export var ROTATION:int = 6
const DIR_N:int = 1
const DIR_E:int = 2
const DIR_S:int = 4
const DIR_W:int = 8
const DIR_EW:int = DIR_E | DIR_W
const DIR_NS:int = DIR_N | DIR_S
const DIR_NESW:int = DIR_N | DIR_E | DIR_S | DIR_W
const DIR_WITHOUT_WE:int = DIR_NESW & (DIR_N | DIR_S)
const DIR_WITHOUT_NS:int = DIR_NESW & (DIR_E | DIR_W)
var ask_to_move:int = 0
var velocity = Vector3(0, 0, 0)

func _ready()->void:
    pass
    
func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        ask_to_move |= DIR_E
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        ask_to_move |= DIR_W
    if (ask_to_move & DIR_EW) == DIR_EW:  # both pressed -> remove:
        ask_to_move &= DIR_WITHOUT_WE

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        ask_to_move |= DIR_N
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        ask_to_move |= DIR_S
    if (ask_to_move & DIR_NS) == DIR_NS:  # both pressed -> remove:
        ask_to_move &= DIR_WITHOUT_NS

func _physics_process(delta):
    if ask_to_move & DIR_E:
        velocity.x = SPEED
        $mesh.rotate_z(deg2rad(-ROTATION))
    elif ask_to_move & DIR_W:
        velocity.x = -SPEED
        $mesh.rotate_z(deg2rad(ROTATION))
    else:
        velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, 0, 0.1)

    if ask_to_move & DIR_N:
        velocity.z = -SPEED
        $mesh.rotate_x(deg2rad(-ROTATION))
    elif ask_to_move & DIR_S:
        velocity.z = SPEED
        $mesh.rotate_x(deg2rad(ROTATION))
    else:
        velocity.z = lerp(velocity.z, 0, 0.1)

    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Comment: FYI `velocity.z = lerp(velocity.z, 0, 0.1)` is equivalent to `velocity.z *= 0.9`. I.e. it is a deceleration, and it is not frame rate independent because it does not use `delta`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But conversely, if there is a big lag, my code ignores player inputs (because _process() is no longer called), but continues/finishes/physical movements

You are correct that with `Input.is_action_pressed` if a key is pressed and released between frames※ it will be ignored.

※: graphics frame if you are using it in `_process` or physics frames if you are using it in `_physics_process`. *Yes, `Input` is aware of the context in which you use it.*

Fun fact: Before Godot 4.1, if a key is pressed and released between frames, `Input.is_action_just_released` will return `true` but `Input.is_action_just_pressed` will return `false`. Starting with Godot 4.1 you will get both returning true, so the code that just checks for `is_action_just_pressed` won't miss the input.

---

> if they had wanted, they would have made a single routine

I'm guessing that with "a single routine" you mean `get_input` and `_physics_process` in the linked example. And to that I agree.

> and they wouldn't have differentiated `_process()` vs `_physics_process()`

I suppose you are not asking why we have these two, since, as you have noted, it is the same logic as in Unity. *Look, I've made my best effort on explaining it at [Make it clear when to use _process and _physics_process](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions/4937#discussioncomment-3198281).*

---

I see that a lot of your concern comes from handling input. So I would suggest to use `_input` for it instead. *I believe there is not Unity equivalent.*

I'm aware that some people want to use `_process` so they "do not miss the player input"… But it is theoretically possible… Except monitors are quicker than humans and some input devices.

In general I would start by - and I would suggest people to to start by - using `Input` in `_physics_process` because we often want to check both physics and input (e.g. is the character on the floor and is the jump button pressed). Then, if you want to make sure you don't miss input, use `_input` instead. *Also use `_input` if you need to handle pointing input, or precise input timing is important.*

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of input. My take on this:

For movement input, you would want to process those in `_physics_process(delta)`, because that is where the movement happens. Pressing a movement key shorter than the duration of a movement frame is ignored. This is usually acceptable.

For attacking/jumping/etc, you either use `_input(event)` or `Input.is_action_just_pressed`  inside `_physics_process(delta)`. Though I just learned from Theraot that this is bugged in Godot < 4.1

If you really want your movements to consider short keypresses (< physics frame update) you should use events and track the actual delta time the key was down. Then do a proportional movement. This will become complex. You would still do the moving in `_physics_process(delta)`.

As for `_process`, I honestly do not see why you would use it for input if you use physics. Only non-physics games could use it I guess, if you make all movements compatible with a variable framerate.

The 'lag' you reference in online games is related to networking, not the graphical framerate of the client.